# How to Resolve Unable To Login Docker

Tags: docker

Following a Docker guides, I try to build a Docker with a command

> sudo gradle build buildDocker

and I get an error:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildDocker'.
Docker execution failed
Command line [docker push vw98075/demo-docker-postgresql:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] returned:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Based on an information on this site, I try to log into docker first and run the command. After running "docker login", I get another error:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.27/auth: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

And I run

> $ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock

whick yields

```
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jun 17 21:47 /var/run/docker.sock
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user is obviously not in the `docker` group. So any docker command will need to be run with `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am going to look into the subject based on your direction.

Comment: For a more permanent solution: add your user to the `docker` group (`sudo usermod -a -G docker YOURUSER`) and logout/login (or reboot) for this change to take effect.